# How to forget session Django 2.1

Tags: python-3.x, session, django-2.0

In my project I need to force Django to forget session and create new one.
Is there the way to do something like session.forget() in view file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.session.flush() deletes the session stored.
Refer this link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/